# White space on either side of navbar html

Tags: html, css, hide, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm very new to writing html and am trying to create a navigation bar for the first time. The issue I'm having is that there is (a varying degree) of white space either side of the bar. I've made a quick mock up and screen shot to show what I mean: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQVMp.png)

I've spent a lot of time over the last couple hours going through questions that are similar and sometimes identical, but none of the solutions I've tried have worked.

My code is as follows:

```css
#navbar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
#navbar ul {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
}
#navbar li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #4682B4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #FAF0E6;
}
#navbar .active {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Reserved</h1>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=“#Experience”>Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=“#Consulting Services“>Consulting Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=“#Contact”>Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=“#About”>About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Also, sorry for any formatting issues with this post!

Comment: Not seeing this replicated in your demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/40fcfrfw/

Comment: That would be the padding on the ul. Give it `padding:0` and you're done.

Comment: Or, alternatively, move the `background-color` from the `ul` to the `#navbar`.

Comment: when i look at it on that link, i don't get the white space on the right, but i still do on the left. However the bar starts inline with the margin after the numbers in css code above i.e theres a 1cm gap from the edge of the window to the start of the bar. Is it supposed to look like that on that editor? When i open the files in chrome or safari I do get whitespace on either side. @JosephMarikle

Comment: Thanks @MrLister that has solved it immediately. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your margin on your unordered list like this:

```
#navbar ul {
    background-color: #FAFAD2;
    margin-left: -40px; /*solution 1 */
    padding:0; /*solution 2 */
}
```

Unless you use a reset css or some framework that gives your `UL`specific instructions, you can expect your browser's instructions to be defaulted. In this case (Chrome) the browser user agent adds a 40px margin start. You have compensate for it to nullify it.

Solution 2 by Mr Lister also works. However, you'll still have to deal with those 40px later on in another encounter. I'd rather indent my ULs what I want, not what the browser think it's best ;)

See the image

[image]

MOst CSS frameworks (Bootstrap, foundation, etc ) or reset.CSS and Modifyer.CSS have this reset in consideration.

See your solved [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/ZQrOVX)

Comment: Setting a margin to `-40px` isn't exactly what I'd call "reset".

Comment: @MrLister I'm adding your suggestion and crediting you. Not exactly a reset, you are right, unless you look at it like this 40 -40 = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this by removing the float on the `<li>`

```
#navbar li {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
}
```

Working example:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/8cbhvj6o/

Answer (score 0):

I think you naar this peace of css

```
#navbar {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; }
```

For the menu in top in your site use 
posistion:fixed; in tour #navbar